# Quiero ejecutar un script que convertí a .exe pero me da error

Tags: python-3.x, vscode, pyinstaller

quiero ejecutar un script que convertí a .exe utilizando pyinstaller 'nombre_del_archivo'. También probé con pyinstaller --clean --onefile -windowed 'nombre_del_archivo'. Después de resolver el otro error ahora se cierra, me puede n ayudar

```html
print("**************************")
print(" Conversor de dinero 2.0")
print("**************************")

menú = int(input("Precione uno para comenzar: "))

if menú == 1:
   print("Meú de opciones: \n")
   print("Presione 1 para convertir de CUP a USD.")
   print("Presione 2 para convertir de USD a CUP. \n")

   opcion = int(input("Seleccione la opción que desea realizar:"))

   if opcion == 1:
    print("Conversor de CUP a USD \n")

    num_uno =float(input("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero ('CUP') que desea convertir en USD: "))
    num_dos =float(input("Ingrese el valor del USD: "))

    resultado = num_uno / num_dos
    print("Usted posee una cantidad de: ", resultado, "USD")

   if opcion == 2:
    print("Conversor de USD a CUP \n")

    num_uno =float(input("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero ('USD') que desea convertir en CUP: "))
    num_dos =float(input("Ingrese el valor del USD: "))

    resultado = num_uno * num_dos
    print("Usted posee una cantidad de: ", resultado, "USD")

print("Fin ☻")
```

Ya resolví el, pero al asignarle datos se cierra el terminal

Comment: que tal, saludos, podrías adjuntar una imagen o en su defecto el texto del error que tienes? saludos

Comment: @sysbot imagen no, texto. Los errores no deberían estar como imagen.

Comment: No soy un aficionado a python, pero eso de que la variable "menu" tenga un acento no mola nada, y print final con el caracter raro.... no se si tendra que ver...

Comment: @Srsole. En Python puedes usar todo el alfabeto, incluyendo eñes y acentos. En Python los string son Unicode, y pueden contener cualquier caracter Unicode (incluyeno emojis).

Comment: Estás compilando un programa que necesita consola sin usar consola. La función input no tiene donde pedirle los datos al usuario. La solución para que se cree la consola es quitar el argumento -windowed

Comment: Todavía soy nuevo eso es un codigo que me dio curiosidad hacerlo

Comment: @DanteS. Muchas gracias ya solucioné el error ☻ me ayudaste mucho ahora puedo seguir aprendiendo. Pero también hay otro código que me error  [enlace (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556295/hola-llevo-unos-d%c3%adas-tratando-de-solucionar-este-error-pero-todav%c3%ada-no-he-lograd)] te agradecería mucho si me ayudas con este también por favor y gracias ☻.

Comment: De nada compañero c: Creo haber dejado un comentario en una pregunta muy parecida que publicaste antes. Pero te lo vuelvo a decir, revisa que el antivirus no haya borrado el archivo.

Comment: @DanteS. muchas gracias por su apoyo ☺. Y se agradecería mucho también si me ayuda en mi otra pregunta.

Comment: Yo te deje un comentario en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556243/quiero-convertir-un-c%c3%b3digo-pyw-a-exe-pero-me-sale-un-error#comment982969_556243). Que diferencia hay entre esa pregunta y la que me pasas?

Comment: @DanteS. Es q la que a a la que te manda el link es otro código que no me deja convertirlo de pyw  a .exe

Comment: @DanteS. El exe de esta pregunta me abre bien pero después de darle la cantidad de cup y el valor del usd se cierra. Que debo hacer ?

Comment: Mil disculpas por dejarte colgado por tanto tiempo... Ha pasado casi un mes y no recuerdo bien. Me podrias pasar la pregunta que mencionabas por favor?

Comment: @DanteS. el programa mientras lo abro por el visual studio me corre bien, pero cuando ejecuto el exe, después de asignarle datos de teclado se cierra. Agradecería su pudieras ayudarme de nuevo ☻☻☻☻☻

Comment: Es normal. El programa hizo su trabajo y finalizó. Ingresas los datos, muestra "fin" en consola y como terminó se cierra. Supongo que visual studio code tiene una consola que no se cierra al finalizar el programa. Una solución sería, por ejemplo, hacer una espera de 3 segundos antes de que el programa finalize o usar input nuevamente y decirle al usuario "presione enter para finalizar".

Comment: @DanteS. muchísimas gracias no se me había ocurrido.

Comment: De nada Osvanis c:

Comment: @DanteS. el programa para cambiar la dirección mac me esta dando otro error, ¿podrías ayudarme? Disculpe las molestias. Por acá esta e[link] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/561083/como-solucionar-el-siguiente-error-typeerror-cannot-use-a-string-pattern-on-a)