# Como solucionar el error TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x, vscode

Hola estoy aprendiendo a cambiar la dirección mac a través de una interfaz pero me sale el siguiente error (Uso python  3.10, soy nuevo en python y estoy aprendiendo a través de un video pero que en el video usan python 2):

```html
sudo python mac_changer1.py -i eth0 -m 00:11:22:33:44:88
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Documents/mac_changer1.py", line 34, in <module>
    current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
  File "/home/kali/Documents/mac_changer1.py", line 25, in get_current_mac
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 200, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

```html
import subprocess
import optparse
import re

def get_argument():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest = "interface", help="Interface para cambiar Direccion MAC",)
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest = "new_mac", help="Nueva Direccción MAC",)
    (options, argument) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.interface:
        parser.error("[-] Por favor indicar una interfaz, usa -help para mas informacion")
    elif not options.new_mac:
        parser.error("[-] Por favor indicar una nueva Direccion MAC, usa -help para mas informacion")
    return options

def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Cambiando Direccion MAC para " + interface + " a " , new_mac)

    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"] )
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])

def get_current_mac(interface):
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface])
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)

    if mac_address_search_result:
        return mac_address_search_result.group(0)
    else:
        print("[-] No se pudo leer la direccion MAC")
    
options = get_argument()

current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
print("Current MAC = " + str(current_mac))

change_mac(options.interface,options.new_mac)

current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
if current_mac == options.new_mac:
    print("[+] Direccion MAC cambio correctamente a " + current_mac)
else:
    print("[-] Direccion MAC no fue cambiado")
```

Este es el código del video :
[image: primera parte]
[image: segunda parte]
[image: tercera parte]
[image: imagen final]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Por favor y gracias ☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻.

Comment: El mensaje es correcto. En el código que muestras `options` no aparece por ninguna parte.

Comment: Pues, depende que es lo que debería ser options. Si se trata de una variable, deberías crearla explicitamente. Si viene de un modulo, hay dos caminos: o hacer from modulo import options (guardando la variable options del modulo en la variable options del programa que está haciendo la importación). O importar options implicitamente con from modulo import *. Dudo que esto sea muy distinto entre Python 2 y 3. Yo volvería a revisar pacientemente el video para ver si me salté algún paso.

Comment: @DanteS. gracias por tu ayuda agregué una imagen con el código del video. Y no me fuciona lo de from import options, tampoco from módulo import

Comment: En el nuevo código que escribiste, pusiste `(options. argument) = ...` ese puntito entre options y argument debería ser una coma no? En la imagen del video está con una coma. Y de nada!

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos ☻. @DanteS. mi código anterior de el convertir de usd a cup se cierra después de asignarle datos de teclado. este es el enlace de la pregunta: [link]()https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/555837/quiero-ejecutar-un-script-que-convert%c3%ad-a-exe-pero-me-da-error

Comment: @DanteS. podrias volver a revisar la pregunta, la edite y le añadí mi progreso y el nuevo error que me esta dando