# como solucionar el siguiente error : TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x

Hola estoy aprendiendo a cambiar la dirección mac a través de una interfaz pero me sale el siguiente error (Uso python 3.10, soy nuevo en python y estoy aprendiendo a través de un video pero que en el video usan python 2):

```html
sudo python mac_changer1.py -i eth0 -m 00:11:22:33:44:88
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Documents/mac_changer1.py", line 34, in <module>
    current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
  File "/home/kali/Documents/mac_changer1.py", line 25, in get_current_mac
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 200, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
import subprocess
import optparse
import re

def get_argument():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest = "interface", help="Interface para cambiar Direccion MAC")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest = "new_mac", help="Nueva Direccción MAC")
    (options, argument) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.interface:
        parser.error("[-] Por favor indicar una interfaz, usa -help para mas informacion")
    elif not options.new_mac:
        parser.error("[-] Por favor indicar una nueva Direccion MAC, usa -help para mas informacion")
    return options

def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Cambiando Direccion MAC para " + interface + " a " , new_mac)

    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"] )
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])

def get_current_mac(interface):
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface])
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)

    if mac_address_search_result:
        return mac_address_search_result.group(0)
    else:
        print("[-] No se pudo leer la direccion MAC")
    
options = get_argument()

current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
print("Current MAC = " + str(current_mac))

change_mac(options.interface,options.new_mac)

current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
if current_mac == options.new_mac:
    print("[+] Direccion MAC cambio correctamente a " + current_mac)
else:
    print("[-] Direccion MAC no fue cambiado")
```

Este es el código del video :
[image: primera parte]
[image: segunda parte]
[image: tercera parte]
[image: imagen final]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Por favor y gracias ☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻☻.

Comment: @CandidMoe es que ese es el código del video mi código está mas arriba

Comment: No estas mostrando el codigo, solo el error

Comment: @CandidMoe a si disculpe.

Comment: @CandidMoe ya lo agregué.

Comment: @CandidMoe lo siento todavía no se había cargado, ya ahora si

Comment: @CandidMoe Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero tengo una duda ¿Por qué al del video le corre de esa forma? y si tengo una interfaz eth0

Comment: No veo ningún video por aqui.

Comment: @CandidMoe a lo que me referí es q por qué, al del video le corre con el Código como esta que lo muestro en las imágenes. Pero como quiera gracias a ti pude resolver mi problema

Comment: ¿Cual video? No veo ningún link a ningún video. No importa en todo caso, no veo videos; leo la documentación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error en el uso de `search()`. El formato correcto es:

```
patron.search(string)
```

El patrón lo debes compilar previamente (una sola vez) y luego lo ocupas para revisar cada línea:

```
patron = re.compile(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w")
def get_current_mac(interface):
    try:
        ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface]).decode()
        mac_address_search_result = patron.search(ifconfig_result)

        if mac_address_search_result:
            return mac_address_search_result.group(0)
        else:
            print("[-] No se pudo leer la direccion MAC")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Además, `subprocess.check_output()` te devuelve **bytes** y tú quieres un **string**. Para convertir bytes a string, aplica la función `decode()`, como se muestra.

Revisa que tu configuración tenga una interfaz `eth0`; la mía (Linux Mint) se llama `enp3s0` ...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero tengo una duda ¿Por qué al del video le corre de esa forma? y si tengo una interfaz eth0 –

Comment: Muchas gracias funcionó la solución ☻